# Error code:1054.Unknown column 'user_id'in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem. When I run this code in MySql Workbench 6.3.3, i have this error : 
Error code:1054.Unknown column 'user_id'in 'field list'. 
What should I do?

use Proiecte;

```
CREATE TABLE users (i INT) ENGINE=MYISAM;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `users` DISABLE KEYS */;  
REPLACE INTO `users` (`user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `gender`, `city`) VALUES  
 (906, 'Ankush', 'Thakur', 'male', 'gurgaon'),  
 (907, 'Anamika', 'Singh', 'female', 'meerut'),  
 (908, 'Shweta', 'Gupta', 'female', 'gurgaon'),  
 (909, 'Rajesh', 'Chauhan', 'male', 'noida'),  
 (911, 'Andrew', 'Symonds', 'male', 'delhi');
 /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `users` ENABLE KEYS */;  
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1 */;  
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
DESC users
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem in create table command:

```
CREATE TABLE users (i INT) ENGINE=MYISAM;
```

you are creating table with only 1 column and then trying to insert the data in 5 columns..

create table with required 5 columns..

```
CREATE TABLE users (`user_id` int(10), `first_name` varchar(100), `last_name` varchar(100), `gender` varchar(10), `city` varchar(100)) ENGINE=MYISAM;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't really understand. Can you please tell me specificly what to correct in my program?

Comment: thanks, but I still have a problem. Soryy, but I'm new to mysql.

Comment: Now I have : Error 1231.Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to value of NULL.

Comment: then remove this command from the file:
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;

Comment: not now I can't see the names and the other data in the table. It appears to have user_id, first_name, etc asa lines and not as columns and no id's, no names, etc...

Comment: I can't post it, because of the reputation :|

Comment: Do you have an e-mail address, so I cand send you the photo?